# Why is a route table not being checked when going into the IGW?

Tags: vpc, amazon-reachable-analyzer

When I send a package to my ec2-instance, no route table is being checked:
[image]

Only when send back:

[image]

Why is no route table checked, when sent into the network?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you attach an **Ingress Route Table** to the `IGW` *(also sometimes called "Gateway" Route Table)*, there is no **explicit** route table controlling traffic from the `IGW` to your `VPC`.

What happens is that the `IGW` translates the `Public IPs` of incoming network packets into the corresponding `Private IPs`, as long as the `Public IPs` are being used within the associated `VPC`. The `Private IPs` follow the default/implicit local-routing rules.

This translation is showcased in the result of your network path analysis with the dual `Inbound header` and `Outbound header` on the `IGW` *(Fields missing in subsequent headers have simply not been changed)*.